Updating SQL Server records with replace
I have many address records that within the records show the address prefix and then 'SR' and then the suffix. What I want to do is replace the 'SR' with 'State Route' and leave the prefix and suffix as is. I've tried:
UPDATE sites
SET address = REPLACE(address, ' SR ', ' State Route ')

This replaces the entire column with ' % State Route % '. I can't really do a left(nnnn)+' State Route' + right(nnnn) because the left and right portion may be different lengths.
EDIT: So I want to to a bulk update using wildcards. In my data I have this:

What I want to do is do a bulk update so that it would show:
1604 State Route 60 
1608 State Route 60 
etc.
I attempted to use the '%' wildcard and ended up with:
'% State Route %' 
'% State Route %' 
etc.
I'm sorry it took so long to update. I used to do this all the time in Oracle, but it's been years and I never did know SQL Server much. Oracle seems a bit closer to the older versions of SQL I'm used to.

What do you mean by the percentage signs in this statement: "This replaces the entire column with ' % State Route % "? Can you edit your question and share some examples of addresses and your desired results as well as what your current attempt is outputting. Your attempt does look to me to be accurate for what you are trying to achieve.

If the entire column gets replaced with ' State Road ' , perhaps the entire coumn is ' SR ', your code is fine. Before updating the column check the values, i.e.  SELECT address, REPLACE(address, ' SR ', ' State Route ') as AddressChanged.

Looks like something similar to Ian Boyd's reply worked. I tried: update Sites
set address = replace(address, ' SR ', ' State Route ')
where siteid = '11874' and that seemed to work. Looks like I don't need the '%' at all.

CREATE TABLE Sites (
  address varchar(200) NOT NULL DEFAULT ''
)

INSERT INTO Sites (address)
VALUES 
('123 SR 45, Springfield, IL 62704'),
('789 E SR 89A, Sedona, AZ 86336'),
('101 SR 10A, Pensacola, FL 32503'),
('202 West SR 120, Elkhart, IN 46514'),
('303 N. SR 200, Starke, FL 32091'),
('404 SR 9 Southeast, Snohomish, WA 98296'),
('505 South SR 49, Mariposa, CA 95338'),
('606 SR 22 W, Circleville, OH 43113'),
('707 East SR 134, Wilmington, OH 45177')

SELECT 
  Address,
  REPLACE(Address, ' SR ', ' State Route ') AS AddressDisplay
FROM Sites




Address
AddressDisplay




123 SR 45, Springfield, IL 62704
123 State Route 45, Springfield, IL 62704


789 E SR 89A, Sedona, AZ 86336
789 E State Route 89A, Sedona, AZ 86336


101 SR 10A, Pensacola, FL 32503
101 State Route 10A, Pensacola, FL 32503


202 West SR 120, Elkhart, IN 46514
202 West State Route 120, Elkhart, IN 46514


303 N. SR 200, Starke, FL 32091
303 N. State Route 200, Starke, FL 32091


404 SR 9 Southeast, Snohomish, WA 98296
404 State Route 9 Southeast, Snohomish, WA 98296


505 South SR 49, Mariposa, CA 95338
505 South State Route 49, Mariposa, CA 95338


606 SR 22 W, Circleville, OH 43113
606 State Route 22 W, Circleville, OH 43113


707 East SR 134, Wilmington, OH 45177
707 East State Route 134, Wilmington, OH 45177



dbFiddle
